# multiple PDO queries and executes in one function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to create 2 queries and executes inside one PHP function with PDO?

my code looks like this, but i think that the variables get mixed up.

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("REPLACE INTO `content` SET `id` = ?, `user_id` = ?, `date` = ?, `type` = ?, `starttime` = ?, `endtime` = ?, `breaktime` = ?, `worktime` = ?, `za` = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $setcontentid);
        $query->bindValue(2, $user_id);
        $query->bindValue(3, $currentdate);
        $query->bindValue(4, $settypedropdown);
        $query->bindValue(5, $starttime);
        $query->bindValue(6, $endtime);
        $query->bindValue(7, $breaktime);
        $query->bindValue(8, $worktime);
        $query->bindValue(9, $za);



        $queryusr = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `current_time_saldo` = ?, `current_holiday_saldo` = ? WHERE `id` = ? ");
        $queryusr->bindValue(1, $currenttimesaldo);
        $queryusr->bindValue(2, $urlaub);
        $queryusr->bindValue(3, $user_id);



        try{

            $query->execute();
            $queryusr->execute();

        } catch(PDOException $e){

            die($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: yes, this is perfectly valid.

Comment: do you need transaction ?

Answer (score -1):

PDO will only allow for a query to execute one at a time.  However if you are using mysql you could always use the mysqli_multi_query function.